# Is it possible to get git committer and author email with Travis API v3?

Tags: travis-ci

In Travis API v2 I would get committer_email and author_email [as described in the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api/#commits).  However, in v3 I only get the name, as In this example:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: token $TRAVIS_API_TOKEN" \
  -H "travis-api-version: 3" \
  'https://travis.example.com/api/repo/acme%my-app/builds?include=build.commit&limit=1'

{
  "@type": "builds",
  ...
  "builds": [
    {
      "@type": "build",
      ...
      "id": 17771810,
      "number": "26506",
      ...
      "commit": {
        "@type": "commit",
        ...
        "message": "foo bar",
        "committed_at": "2022-08-22T06:55:55Z",
        "committer": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "avatar_url": "https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/foobar"
        },
        "author": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "avatar_url": "https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/foobar"
        }
```

The commit and author data in the API is just [defined as an Object](https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/commit#Commit) without further definition:

```
committer   Object  Committer data.
author      Object  Committer data.
```

I'm testing this on an on-site install of Travis CI v3 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Travis CI support:

> I have been discussing this with one of the Enterprise Engineers and it seems like it was intended not to expose the email information on the Travis CI API v3, in this case, the behaviour is expected, however, you will still have the author name and commuter name as you have mentioned.

Luckily Travis CI API v2 should still be available for the Travis CI Enterprise 3.x instance, so I'll be able to get the email for a while longer.